# Showing JSON results neatly in a webpage

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to figure out how to get JSON results and show them in a template I have built.

I have a page that has checkboxes, when the check boxes are checked the script refines the search. So far I have a created a script that checks to see if a user has checked a box. A separate PHP script then runs a query on an SQL database - returning the results live.

I have so far managed to get this to return the results as JSON in the console and 'stringified' in the webpage.

How do I take the JSON results and show them neatly on the webpage? i.e

```
Name: 'name', Locale: 'locale'
Name: 'name', Locale: 'locale'
Name: 'name', Locale: 'locale'
```

This is my Ajax code at the moment:

```
var ajaxResult=[];
function updateEmployees(opts){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "search.php",
dataType : 'json',
cache: false,
data: {filterOpts: opts},
success:function(data)      {
        ajaxResult.push(data);
     }
});
}
```

This is the javascript checkbox code:

```
var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
var opts = getEmployeeFilterOptions();
updateEmployees(opts);

console.log(ajaxResult)
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(ajaxResult);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myJSON;

});
updateEmployees();
```

Thanks for your help in advance. I've spent a couple of days trying to figure this out!

EDIT - PHP script I am using

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB', '**', '**');
$select = 'SELECT name, locale, website';
$from = ' FROM theList';
$where = ' WHERE TRUE';
$opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts'])? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array('');
if (in_array("pub", $opts)){
$where .= " AND pub = 1";
}
if (in_array("bar", $opts)){
$where .= " AND bar = 1";
}
if (in_array("restaurant", $opts)){
$where .= " AND restaurant = 1";
}
if (in_array("club", $opts)){
$where .= " AND club = 1";
}
if (in_array("locale-a", $opts)){
$where .= " AND locale = 'south'";
}
if (in_array("locale-b", $opts)){
$where .= " AND locale = 'west'";
}

$sql = $select . $from . $where;
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo($json);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here.

**1.** Your results set will grow every time a checkbox changes since you're pushing a new element to the results array.  If you're fetching the full dataset every time, this is unnecessary.

**2.** AJAX performs asynchronously, your code is written with expectation that it's synchronous.

This...

```
console.log(ajaxResult)
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(ajaxResult);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myJSON;

});
updateEmployees();
```

...is expecting data that doesn't exist yet.

The process goes:

1. **user clicks checkbox**
2. submit selections to server to query database
3. wait for response
4. handle result when response received

However, the above code is already on step 4 before step 3 has completed.  You need to tell the ajax call what to do when it's received the response:

```
// send selections to server
function updateEmployees(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "search.php",
        dataType : 'json',
        cache: false,
         // serialize checked boxes to a query string like "check1=on&check2=on"
        data: $('input:checkbox').serialize(),
        success: handleResults
    });
}

// handle filtered results
function handleResults(data) {
    // same as document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML
    $('#demo').html(
        JSON.stringify(data)
    );
}

// add events to checkboxes
$('input:checkbox').change(updateEmployees);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's still not working... I have added the PHP script I am using - if you were able to take another look!

Comment: `in_array` needs to be `array_key_exists`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use stringify method with these params:

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(ajaxResult, null, 2);
```